# Finding the Point of Convergence of a Series of Lines

Tags: linear-algebra, convergence-divergence

I've built a collection of 3 lines. These lines are create dynamically. But, for the sake of communication, I've provided a sample data structure below.

Each line is made of a series of points with X,Y coordinates. In addition, I have the slope of line. Beyond the three lines, I have a threshold.

A lot of times, my lines are incomplete. However, assuming they were to continue to be drawn, I'd like to find the point at which they converge. The threshold is a way of saying "close enough". My question is, how do I calculate the point of convergence using the information I have?

```
var threshold = 0.2;
var lines = [
  { 
    slope:0.2, 
    points: [
      { x:405, y:80 },
      { x:410, y:81 },
      { x:415, y:82 }
    ]
  },
  {
    slope:0.384615,
    points: [
      { x:213, y:80 },
      { x:215.6, y:81 },
      { x:218.2, y:82 }
    ]
  },
  {
    slope:0.31250,
    points: [
      { x:261, y:80 },
      { x:264.2, y:81 },
      { x:267.4, y:82 }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: Given two non-parallel lines, one can find when they eventually intersect one another. However, with three lines, it is most likely that the three lines will not all intersect all at the same spot (each pair might intersect at unique locations).

Comment: @benguin - I understand that. That's why I have a "threshold". Or maybe a better way of asking the question is, at what point will the lines be the closest together?

Comment: If none of the three lines are parallel to one another and if they don't all intersect at a point, then the three lines will intersect at three points and form a triangle. Would using the center of the triangle (say the centroid) be suitable for this threshold?

Comment: @benguin - I believe so. However, These lines are generated from some formulas. Its just the values in these formulas are changing. For that reason, I'm fairly certain the lines will eventually converge. There isn't going to be something like a triangle formed. Instead the trend is for the lines to converge. I'm just trying to figure out where, and if they don't ever converge, i'm trying to find the closes point.